# Android onUpgrade, database structure change and data handling

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Got some problems that I don't really know how to solve. I have stored a TimeStamp in my SQLite Database as a String(not very clever;-)), and know I need to convert that to a millisecond represantation as a long in the database. The reason for this is that I want to fetch the TimeStamp and represent it correctly according to the devices locale.

However, for this to happen I need to do some database migration in the onUpgrade() method. I have done this before and the structure changes are no problem, the problem is that I want to take the old TimeStamps represented as  Strings, convert them to longs and insert them into the new columns.

The wanted migration flow would be something like this.

1. Rename existing table to tmp_TableName
2. Create new table TableName with the new TimeStamp column of datatype long
3. Insert the existing values from tmp_table to the new table AND at this stage the existing TimeStamps should be converted to milliseconds and stored into the new table
4. Drop tmp table

It's point number 3 that's the problem. Is it possible to handle any existing data before it's inserted in the new table in onUpgrade()? I have not seen any examples on this, and I don't know if it's possible.
What's the correct way of handling situations as this?

Answer (score 0):

> It's point number 3 that's the problem. Is it possible to handle any
>   existing data before it's inserted in the new table in onUpgrade()? I
>   have not seen any examples on this, and I don't know if it's possible.
>   What's the correct way of handling situations as this?

your assumptions are correct, and yes you can use `onUpgrade()` to migrate the table's content. Also notice that `onUpgrade()` runs in a transaction and Android guarantees the rollback is the migration is not successful

Comment: Okey, sounds good that onUpgrade() runs in a transaction and guarantees a rollback, didn't actually know that.
Do you know any documentation describing the correct way of migrating the tables content? Thanks!

Comment: no that I know. But I did the same  thing in the past and it worked